# What does the new inspect element bring to Firefox that Firebug does not have?

Tags: firefox, web-development

When doing web development with Firefox I've always used the Firebug add-on. Now with the upgrades to Firefox, there is a new built in feature of 'Inspect Element'. What does this new feature bring to the table in comparison to Firebug?

Comment: *>  Now with the upgrades to Firefox, there is a new built in feature of 'Inspect Element'.*   `o.O`   That's (almost) always been there. I never used Firebug but have always had a `Inspect Element` option; first with the *DOM-Inspector* addon, a little then later (e.g., ~2.0-3.0) it was built-in. I definitely remember there being a built-in one because I pondered removing the DOM-Inspector, but decided against it because the built-in one was good, but not quite as good as the add-on.

Comment: I've used firefox for years, and for some reason was always under the impression that the only way to have a web development tool was to use firebug. Now since firefox has gotten onto their 'rapid release' schedule, I"ve just now noticed that they've integrated 'web developer' into their menu items and have included this suite of tools. So by habit it's always been firebug, and for me, the built in tool is new.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pretty awesome 3D view:

[image]

- [How to enable the new 3D page inspector view in Firefox 11](https://superuser.com/questions/401005/how-to-enable-the-new-3d-page-inspector-view-in-firefox-11)

Comment: While I admit, that is a pretty awesome feature, how would you actually  use it for anything web development wise?

Comment: @Chris: I could bring myself to imagine *some* use for it, but I never needed it. Overall, I think the element inspector if Firefox is a gimmick at best, especially compared to Firebug.