# Does Firefox still have the 3D DOM viewer?

Tags: firefox

I can't seem to make out this little feature that was once there in Firefox.

The 3D button that was there in an earlier version of the dev tools is gone and I can't seem to find any trace of this feature anywhere. If it's still there, how do I enable it?

Comment: Can you please reconsider to change your accepted answer? Firefox 47 changed this and that 3D functionality completely removed now

Comment: 2020: https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/46.0.1/mac/en-US/
This version still works on a mac just turn in on in the inspector settings and make sure not turn off auto-updates. If you need another FF version install latest "Developer Edition" so you can run 2 versions at the same time.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

## [From Firefox 47 onwards, built-in 3D view is no longer available.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/3D_View)

There is an add-on that offers the same functionality: [Tilt 3D](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tilt/).

Note: just like the built-in version, the add-on does not work in multiprocess Firefox.

**Tilt 3D IS Not compatible with Firefox Quantum.**

Comment: Are you sure, it doesn't work in pultiprocess e10s? see [how-to-check-if-multiprocess-e10s-option-is-enabled-in-your-firefox](http://superuser.com/questions/1096974/)

Comment: @rubo77 Yes , I checked it in Firefox Developer Edition. Tild 3D doesn't work in Multiprocess e10s.

Comment: So it seems, like multiprocess must be disabled in my firefox 47 then, cause Tild 3D works. (I didn't disable it manualy)

Comment: it seems that Tilt 3D does not support Firefox Quantum version - any suggestions to alternative?

Comment: @serup , You are right but I couldn't find any other alternative. Let us know if you find any.

Comment: This has started showing up in Edge builds now, of all places.

Comment: the addon link is not available anymore, is there another addon?

Comment: Edge Chromium is supposed to have this now:
https://techdows.com/2019/08/microsoft-is-working-to-bring-3d-view-to-chromium-now-can-be-enabled-in-new-edge-browser.html

Answer (score 70):

Up until Firefox version 47: If you right click and select "Inspect Element" and then click the gear icon at the left hand side of the toolbox menu you should see "Available Toolbox Buttons" under which appears "3D View".

[image]

Clicking this will add a new icon to the toolbox menu that when clicked will show the 3D Dom view.

[image]

Comment: It seems like this should be enabled by default. Is it not?

Comment: It was not enabled by default in the version that I used when replying to the question.

Comment: Looks like it has been completely removed from the firefox developer edition.  What a shame as it really set it apart from Chrome.

Comment: Why did they bury it like this? Frustrating user experience.

Comment: It's not completely removed from FF; it's disabled while e10s (multiprocess) is enabled. Turn it off as per drewfg's answer below

Comment: "From Firefox 47 onwards, 3D view is no longer available. There is an add-on that offers the same functionality: Tilt 3D. However, note that just like the built-in version, the add-on does not work in multiprocess Firefox." Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/3D_View

Comment: You are right, this answer is outdated since FF 47, @ThorOdinson 's Answer below should be the accepted. [Tilt 3D](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tilt/) works quite well

Comment: Still using this in 2020:
https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/46.0.1/mac/en-US/Firefox%2046.0.1.dmg
And it works like charm 46.0.1

Answer (score 9):

Goto: Preferences->General Uncheck "Enable multi-process Firefox Developer Edition"

Restart Firefox

Goto: Developer tool bar [Tool Box Options], "3D View" check box should now show under "Available Toolbox Buttons", make sure this is checked and you are good.

Comment: I cannot find that option in my german Firefox 47.0, maybe it is called something like `electrolysis` or `e10s` in `about:config`. Anyway: **I think it is not a good Idea to disable the new feature of multiprocessor support**

Answer (score 7):

I know this question is in regards to FireFox, but you can get this feature in Chrome as well (Firefox won't let you insert JS as a bookmark):

[image: 3D View Chrome]

Add this javascript code as a bookmark url:

```
javascript:void function(b,p)%7Bfunction l(k,c,b,e,g,d,f)%7Breturn"<div style%3D%27position:absolute%3B-webkit-transform-origin: 0 0 0%3B"%2B("background:"%2Bf%2B"%3B")%2B("width:"%2Be%2B"px%3B height:"%2Bg%2B"px%3B")%2B("-webkit-transform:"%2B("translate3d("%2Bk%2B"px,"%2Bc%2B"px,"%2Bb%2B"px)")%2B("rotateX(270deg) rotateY("%2Bd%2B"deg)")%2B"%3B")%2B"%27></div>"%7Dfunction o(k,c,d,f)%7Bfor(var j%3Dk.childNodes,n%3Dj.length,m%3D0%3Bm<n%3Bm%2B%2B)%7Bvar a%3Dj%5Bm%5D%3Bif(1%3D%3D%3Da.nodeType)%7Ba.style.overflow%3D"visible"%3Ba.style.WebkitTransformStyle%3D"preserve-3d"%3Ba.style.WebkitTransform%3D"translateZ("%2B(b%2B(n-m)*q).toFixed(3)%2B"px)"%3Bvar h%3Dd,i%3Df%3Ba.offsetParent%3D%3D%3Dk%26%26(h%2B%3Dk.offsetLeft,i%2B%3Dk.offsetTop)%3Bo(a,c%2B1,h,i)%3Be%2B%3Dl(h%2Ba.offsetLeft,i%2Ba.offsetTop,(c%2B1)*b,a.offsetWidth,b,0,g%5Bc%25(g.length-1)%5D)%3Be%2B%3Dl(h%2Ba.offsetLeft%2Ba.offsetWidth,i%2Ba.offsetTop,(c%2B1)*b,a.offsetHeight,b,270,g%5Bc%25(g.length-1)%5D)%3Be%2B%3Dl(h%2Ba.offsetLeft,i%2Ba.offsetTop%2Ba.offsetHeight,(c%2B1)*b,a.offsetWidth,b,0,g%5Bc%25(g.length-1)%5D)%3Be%2B%3Dl(h%2Ba.offsetLeft,i%2Ba.offsetTop,(c%2B1)*b,a.offsetHeight,b,270,g%5Bc%25(g.length-1)%5D)%7D%7D%7Dvar g%3D"%23C33,%23ea4c88,%23663399,%230066cc,%23669900,%23ffcc33,%23ff9900,%23996633".split(","),q%3D0.001,e%3D"",d%3Ddocument.body%3Bd.style.overflow%3D"visible"%3Bd.style.WebkitTransformStyle%3D"preserve-3d"%3Bd.style.WebkitPerspective%3Dp%3Bvar r%3D(window.innerWidth/2).toFixed(2),s%3D(window.innerHeight/2).toFixed(2)%3Bd.style.WebkitPerspectiveOrigin%3Dd.style.WebkitTransformOrigin%3Dr%2B"px "%2Bs%2B"px"%3Bo(d,0,0,0)%3Bvar f%3Ddocument.createElement("DIV")%3Bf.style.display%3D"none"%3Bf.style.position%3D"absolute"%3Bf.style.top%3D0%3Bf.innerHTML%3De%3Bd.appendChild(f)%3Bvar j%3D"NO_FACES"%3Bdocument.addEventListener("mousemove",function(b)%7Bif("DISABLED"!%3D%3Dj)%7Bvar c%3Db.screenX/screen.width,b%3D(360*(1-b.screenY/screen.height)-180).toFixed(2),c%3D(360*c-180).toFixed(2)%3Bd.style.WebkitTransform%3D"rotateX("%2Bb%2B"deg) rotateY("%2Bc%2B"deg)"%7D%7D,!0)%3Bdocument.addEventListener("mouseup",function()%7Bswitch(j)%7Bcase "NO_FACES":j%3D"FACES"%3Bf.style.display%3D""%3Bbreak%3Bcase "FACES":j%3D"NO_FACES",f.style.display%3D"none"%7D%7D,!0)%7D(25,5E3)%3B
```

[image: Instructions for 3D view]

Once added click the bookmark on any website. You can click to show outlines and drag to view like in Firefox.

Comment: It's ok, but it's just not the same

Comment: I quickly created [a tiny script](https://gist.github.com/corentinbettiol/85a8938175f89a15ac353b2c8b492e19) that looks more like firefox tilt feature.

Answer (score 4):

**Update**: It's been removed from FF 47 onwards, but is available in an [add-on](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/3D_View).

It seems FF updates might disable this. FF 38 has changed the settings icon location.

**Firefox 38 - cube and cog on the right:**

[image: Firefox 38]

Answer (score 2):

**Firefox 46.0** still can be downloaded here : https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/46.0/

And **Tilt 3D** module here (from Firefox 46.0) :
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tilt/

Render view seems better with **Tilt 3D** than with native **3D View** from Web Developer Tools :

[Screenshot comparison between Tilt 3D and 3D View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpL8F.jpg)

Comment: thx for the links, saved me some lifetime.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at Microsofts Edge Browser.

I have version *Version 79.0.283.0 (Official build) canary (64-bit)*. Put `edge://flags/` in the address bar and enable *Developer Tools experiments*. Open the developer tools and press *Control+Shift+P* and search *Experiments* and find *Enable DOM 3D view*.

Now you can use *Ctrl+Shift+P* > *DOM 3D View*.

It's not a Firefox solution but it worked for me.

I found out about it [here](https://twitter.com/EdgeDevTools/status/1158485601798119424).

Answer (score 1):

It's gone after version 46.
A solution to this is to Google "Firefox 46 download"
Install that version and rename it (on Mac) to something like firefox-45 to keep the updated version as well. Launch version 45 and turn automatic updates off. You can now enable the 3D view and see the page in 3D and tilt it.

Hope that works for you.