# How to check if multiprocess e10s option is enabled in your Firefox

Tags: firefox

Since Firefox 47 multi-process option Electrolysis (e10s) is enabled, but I am afraid, my Firefox still only uses one process.

There are a lot of options fingering with this subject in `about:config`:

```
browser.tabs.remote.autostart
extensions.e10sBlockedByAddons
extensions.e10sBlocksEnabling
```

How can I verify that all options are set right?
Which options enable/disable the multi-process capability?
How do I find out if an Addon blocks this option?

Comment: My configuration is: 
browser.tabs.remote.autostart : true,
 extensions.e10sBlockedByAddons : false,
 extensions.e10sBlocksEnabling : true  .

Comment: The first two options browser.tabs.remote.autostart and extensions.e10sBlockedByAddons is important and third extensions.e10sBlocksEnabling doesn't affected much .
One important point is that extensions.e10sBlockedByAddons : false may break some of your addons.

Comment: @Thor, can you post this as answer, so i can reward you?

Comment: I am glad that you find my comment useful . Posted that as an answer but it seems that you answered it way better than me.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Open the site `about:support` in Firefox, which indicates if e10s is enabled.

There is a line "Multi-process staged rollout", which would be set to `true` if e10s is enabled. Also look for a number higher than 0 in the "Multiprocess Windows" entry (this is translated to your locale, e.g. "Fenster mit mehreren Prozessen" and "Web-Inhaltsprozesse" in german).

e.g., accessibility, add-ons can trigger disabling this feature.

On this site you can check, if add-ons, you are using are compatible: http://arewee10syet.com/. There is also a [mozilla site to check compatibility](https://compatibility-lookup.services.mozilla.com/), you find the addon-id in the extension-filenames in your profile folder, for example the "Tab Groups" add-on has the id `tabgroups@quicksaver` and is incompatible with e10s.

If you would like to opt-in to test the feature anyway, open `about:config` and toggle `browser.tabs.remote.autostart` to `true`. On your next restart, e10s should be active.

#### Force Enable

**Don't try this on Android, or it will break your Firefox app completely!**

On desktops,
if you've tried enabling e10s but about:support indicates that e10s is disabled (e.g., accessibility, add-ons can trigger this), you can force e10s on for testing purposes. Within `about:config` create a new `boolean` pref named `browser.tabs.remote.force-enable` and set it to `true`. This is not encouraged, use it at your own risk!

(I tried it anyway and it worked, even with Tab Groups Addon still enabled but it's risky!)

*Source: https://wiki.mozilla.org/Electrolysis#Force_Enable*

Comment: `browser.tabs.remote.force-enable` worked for me. (The normal settings kept getting changed on start back to single process.)

Answer (score 13):

My configuration is:

`browser.tabs.remote.autostart : true`

`extensions.e10sBlockedByAddons : false`

`extensions.e10sBlocksEnabling : true`

After these setting my `about:support` is showing that multiprocess Windows is enabled by user(me).

[image]

The first two options 
`browser.tabs.remote.autostart` and `extensions.e10sBlockedByAddons` is important and third `extensions.e10sBlocksEnabling` doesn't seems to affect much. One important point is that `extensions.e10sBlockedByAddons : false` may break some of your addons.

Comment: Why browser.tabs.remote.autostart? That doesn't Sound related

Comment: @rubo77 The word "remote" here really mean "E10s". It refers to "process", in case you are wondering.

Comment: In my case setting `extensions.e10sBlockedByAddons=false` for FF v53 was enough to see `1/1 (Enabled by default)` in `about:support`.

Comment: Hi @dma_k , It seems that `extensions.e10sBlockedByAddons` not available in my FF 53 (Ubuntu X64) anymore. BTW thanks for your info.

Answer (score 0):

I opted out of multi-processing in version 64.0.2 of Firefox by going to `about:debugging#workers` and click `Opt out of multiple content processes`:

[image: service worker debugging]

I didn't make a mental note of which config option it was changing, and once opted out, there was no button to opt in!

#### Fortunately, I found the config value: `dom.ipc.multiOptOut`. The value should be empty.