# Firefox find out what accessibility disabled e10s

Tags: windows-10, firefox

With the release of Firefox 52 this week, Windows 8 and 10 touchscreen users can now use e10s (provided they also have add-on support).

When I went into about:support today, I found that I was still disabled by an accessibility.

I have seen [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1096974/how-to-check-if-multiprocess-e10s-option-is-enabled-in-your-firefox) question, which answers the basics of how to force enable e10s, but I would like to know if there is a way to tell what accessibility feature blocked my use of e10s.

Comment: I encountered a similar problem after I had used the [Windows 10 touch keyboard](https://www.howtogeek.com/240288/how-to-use-the-on-screen-keyboard-on-windows-7-8-and-10/) in the Notification Area. After that, Firefox `about:support` showed that `Multiprocess Windows` was disabled due to an accessibility feature.  Ultimately, I had to ensure that my Firefox Sync had a good copy of all my data and then [delete/recreate my Firefox profile](https://support.mozilla.org/t5/Install-and-Update/Use-the-Profile-Manager-to-create-and-remove-Firefox-profiles/ta-p/2914) to alleviate the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if multiprocess e10s option is enabled in your Firefox](http://superuser.com/questions/1096974/how-to-check-if-multiprocess-e10s-option-is-enabled-in-your-firefox)

Comment: @Run5k I updated the question. I Know about that question (it helped me force-enable), but I would like to identify what specific accessibility features disabled e10s. I will look into the touch keyboard, but I don't think that is it.

Comment: IIRC, when I enabled the touch keyboard there was actually a message within Firefox that informed me of the change, but it has been quite a while.  Even though I *did* know which accessibility feature disabled `Multiprocess Windows`, I still couldn't find a way to undo it.  As I said, I finally just created a new Firefox profile and then `Multiprocess Windows` was enabled by default.

Comment: @Run5k. Well I never got a warning, and the accessibility.loadedinlastsession flag is still reporting true, suggesting that it is something else.

Comment: In addition to the configuration within [Options > Advanced > General > Accessibility](https://support.mozilla.org/t5/Manage-preferences-and-add-ons/Advanced-panel-Accessibility-browsing-network-updates-and-other/ta-p/3333), there are other Mozilla articles available that describe [additional accessibility features in Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/t5/Learn-the-Basics-get-started/Accessibility-features-in-Firefox-Make-Firefox-and-web-content/ta-p/3516). Hopefully they can point you in the right direction.  If not, as I said before, it may be prudent to just create a new Firefox profile.