# How to change Firefox's number of content process limit?

Tags: windows-7, firefox, process

According to [How to Change Content Process Limit in Firefox Browser](http://www.trishtech.com/2017/08/change-content-process-limit-in-firefox/) the default for the content process limit since FF 55 is *4* and this is also mentioned on [Firefox's performance settings](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/performance-settings) page.

Well, I'm running 56.0.2 (64-Bit) here and the value is set to *1* and I can't change it (the drop-down box is grayed out).

Starting FF in safe-mode does neither change the value nor activate the drop-down box.

There are three `dom.ipc.processCount[...]` settings in *about:config* set to `1`. Q1: Is this the place to change the setting if it is not changeable via the UI?

Q2: Why is it not changeable via the UI? Q3: How to fix this?

Comment: Go to `about:support` and there'll be a line that tells you why multiprocess is disabled. Usually either incompatible addon or recent use of accessibility APIs.

Comment: @Bob Without the newly created setting described in [my answer](https://superuser.com/a/1264630/516482) `about:support` told me _Multiprocess Windows: 0/2 (deactivated by Add-on)_. Now it says _2/2 (activated by user)_ but the line _Web content processes_ wasn't available at all before – despite the number of processes having been _1_.

Comment: If you really feel like changing it and it doesn't work with normal Firefox, then you might want to get Firefox Beta or Nightly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer to Q1:

Changing the setting `dom.ipc.processCount` in `about:config` changes the value in the UI's drop-down box accordingly. I set it to `7`.

But this is just the first part of the story:

- There was no line *Application Basics* →  *Web content processes* in `about:support` after that.
- I had to create a new *Boolean* setting in `about:config` (according to a hint from [dom.ipc.processCount](https://forum.golem.de/kommentare/internet/mozilla-firefox-54-bringt-komplette-multi-prozess-architektur/dom.ipc.processcount/110058,4831402,4831402,read.html); a C&P backup of your FF profile folder before is recommended there):

  `browser.tabs.remote.force-enable` = `true`
- After a restart there's a line *Web content processes*: *8/7* in `about:support` and there are 10 `firefox.exe` processes displayed in the Task Manager.

*8/7* and *10* still gives me riddles but my i7-6700 (4/8 cores/threads) is still smiling with this 9 more processes and FF behaves much more responsive now.

Just two questions to go.

#### UPDATE

See also the answers to [How to check if multiprocess e10s option is enabled in your Firefox](https://superuser.com/q/1096974/516482).

According to [dma_k's comment to this answer there](https://superuser.com/a/1101583/516482) the following finally works here:

- `browser.tabs.remote.autostart` = `true`
- `browser.tabs.remote.autostart.2` = `true` (didn't touch that)
- `browser.tabs.remote.force-enable` = `false` (the newly created above)
- `extensions.e10sBlockedByAddons` = `false` (mentioned in dma_k's comment)

Comment: I'm still thinking if I set lower to how much core of my laptop, will it make the CPU usage smaller. hmm..

Answer (score 2):

There are reasons Firefox disables this dropdown on purpose. (In my opinion this is bad UX because it will only confuse the average end user). Most obvious would be incompatible addons. However since you tested in safe mode addons should be disabled, but maybe they have set safe mode to only allow one process since its a newer feature.

You can check about:config to verify `browser.tabs.remote.autostart` is enabled. In my case I did this manually and had Electrolisys/Content Processes working in version 54 but it seems someone cocked something up with the 56 release, to my suprise it was locked to 1 as you are describing. This was just using the normal Release channel updates. I can only enable it now by setting `browser.tabs.remote.force-enable` which is not advised. Then you can use the UI to select the number of processes. (So I changed it back after seeing that force-enable worked).

Comment: `browser.tabs.remote.autostart` = `false` here. If I set `browser.tabs.remote.force-enable` = `false` now the drop-down box still contains _7_ but but it's deactivated and there's again just on `firefox.exe` process.  I guess this is not only confusing _the average end user._

Comment: Uhm yes I agree. I was just saying that it worked in the past without using the force method. Did I mix anything up in my anwser?

Comment: I do not see anything you mixed up. I did, on the other hand, in my previous comment: 2 consecutive "but"s and on**e** missing "e". :)